# 2D Conformal Group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

I am trying to check my understanding of the conformal group.  We know $l_{0} = -z\partial_{z}$ for this particular value of the Witt algebra.  We then can make the substitution $z = re^{i\phi}$, which should lead to $$l_{0} = -\frac{1}{2}r\partial_{r} + \frac{i}{2}\partial_{\phi}  \tag{1}.$$  My issue is I cannot seem to get (1) and think I might be making a silly mistake.

Given $z = re^{i\phi}$, $l_{0} = -(re^{i\phi})\partial(re^{i\phi}) = -(re^{i\phi})(e^{i\phi}\partial_{r}+ire^{i\phi}\partial_{\phi})=-(re^{2i\phi}\partial_{r} + ir^{2}e^{2i\phi}\partial_{\phi})$ (2).

(2) $\neq$ (1), so what did I miss?

Comment: I took this from Blumenhagen's book, pg 14.  He mentions it and I want to derive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: do the right thing.
$$
(z,\bar z)\mapsto (r,\phi) ,  \\ r=\sqrt{z\bar z}, \qquad \phi= {1\over 2i}\log(z/\bar z),\\
\partial_z= (\partial_z r )~~\partial_r + (\partial_z \phi )~~ \partial_\phi ~~.  
$$

Comment: Hi Cosmas, thank you for your input.  It does work out, as I just did it.  Where or how did you obtain the identity for $\phi$?  I did another problem concerning change of variables with this knowledge and it works.  I just want to cement it correctly so I don't make this mistake again.  If I understand this, the $\partial_{r}$ and $\partial_{\phi}$ are now the basis vectors in the new coordinate frame with components $\partial_{z}r$ and $\partial_{z}\phi$ respectively in your third line.  How is that transformation derived?

Comment: This is no different than any  change of 2 variables; have you had multivariable calculus? This is the formula for transforming gradients. You *do* understand that $\partial_z \bar z =0$, so $z$ is independent of $\bar z$, right?

Comment: Yes, I was just unfamiliar with the fact that $\phi$ was given in terms of a log relation.  I didn't recall this of the top of my head.  Plus if I didn't understand that, I wouldn't have been able to reproduce the result with the information I learned from you.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps, mindful of [$(x,y)\mapsto (r,\phi)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Differential_calculus). Likewise, $(z,\bar z)\mapsto (x,y)$. Recall $z/\bar z = \exp (2i\phi)$.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am going to make sure this mistake doesn't happen to me again!